# Put a part of a POST request in variable

Tags: c#

I did a POST request code pointing to an API to do an automatic exchange program.
Here is the code:

```
string webAddr = "https://shapeshift.io/shift";

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{ \"withdrawal\" : \"***ADDRESS WITH LETTER AND NUMBER***\", \"pair\" : \"eth_xmr\" }";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseText);
            }
```

And after executing the code, I'm getting this in the console

```
{"orderId":"1f90346c-c6d4-4d89-a24c-78b2bbdb6292","deposit":"0x534aa684274b4711f65b2d0e2e403cb169201255","depositType":"ETH","withdrawal":"***ADDRESS WITH LETTER AND NUMBER***","withdrawalType":"XMR"
```

Now, I want to put the address from deposit that I'm getting from the API into a string variable. I tried some code but I can't make it working. So how can I put this address in a string variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deserialize the response and get from there that you want. In order to do so you could define a class, let's name it `ApiResponse`:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("orderId")]
    public string orderId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deposit")]
    public string deposit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("depositType")]
    public string depositType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("withdrawal")]
    public string withdrawal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("withdrawalType")]
    public string withdrawalType { get; set; }
}
```

and then after

```
var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

make the deserialization:

```
var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(responseText);
```

I have used the [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library. So if you haven't isntall it, you should do so or you could make use of another library and change correspondingly the above code.